# How can I disable nginx logging with limit_conn and limit_req?

Tags: nginx

How can I completely disable logging from HttpLimitConnModule and HttpLimitReqModule?

At least limit the damage done from extensive logging in case of a DOS-attack. I still want some error-logging but not when the request is denied.

Such messages:
`2013/07/12 20:20:10 [error] 31544#0: *78 limiting requests, excess: 0.519 by zone "limit", client: *.*.*.*, server: example.com, request: "GET /static.html HTTP/1.1", host: "example.com", referrer: ""`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to enable error_log just where it is needed.

```
server {
    error_log   /dev/null crit;

    location ~\.php$ {
        error_log   /var/log/nginx_error.log;
    }
}
```